# Any way to reboot an iOS Device that is connected to a USB port via terminal (Mac terminal) and enter the appleid through command line?

Tags: ios, iphone, macos

Ok, SO here is my thing.

I am working on test automation on iOS devices. And here is what I need to do

1. Detect ios devices connected to through USB hub(achieved)
2. Reboot the device using its unique udid (achieved)
3. Upon rebooting, the device will prompt to enter apple id. Now, I want to know is there any way I can enter the apple id to device prompt through my command line.?

I have been on this since 2 days, and without any luck.

Can anybody here, help me out with a probable solution.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it installing Apple configurator AND issuing comands like cfgutil.

If you simply type in terminal:

cfgutil

You can see.. (among others...)

**restart
        Reboot attached devices. (supervised only)**